# How do i work with EF4 using this table structure

Tags: database-design, entity-framework-4

I have a common table to store Comments on my system like this:

```
id   <- PK
Text <- user content
userId
createdAt
commentType <- a discriminator, to know which entity is the parent of this comment ie: N: News, A:Articles, and so on...
typeId <- Id of the parent entity
```

I worked before with this type of structure using nhibernate like this:

```
mapping.HasMany(x=> x.Comments)
.Cascade.All()
.Inverse()
.Where("commentType='A'")
.KeyColumn("typeId")
```

How do i work this type of structure on EF4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think [this tutorial](http://www.robbagby.com/entity-framework/entity-framework-modeling-table-per-hierarchy-inheritance/) is what you are looking for.

basically you have to create an entity for each kind of descriptor, and the where is housed in the entity, not the mapping.